# RegEx to validate consecutive underscores with jQuery validator

Tags: jquery, validation

I've problem in adding a jQuery validation plugin method. I want to validate a field if it does not contain two consecutive underscores eg. __ or *_* etc.
There's something wrong with the matching pattern. I'm trying following:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("valid_word", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /[~__~]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Invalid word");
```

The above method will not accept a word if it does not include one or more underscores, so this is not what I want. I want it not to accept the word if it has consecutive underscores.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should work:

```
/^((?!__).)*$/
```

Replace your pattern with the above.

For help testing Regex, I recommend trying out [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)